# Issue with inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

I've got an issue with the non-allowed multiple inheritance in C#

Following scenario:

```
class MasterCamera { ... }

class CameraFromManufacturerA : MasterCamera { ... }

class CameraFromManufacturerB : MasterCamera { ... }

class CameraFromManufacturerC : MasterCamera { ... }
```

`MasterCamera` provides some functionality like `StartCamera()`, `ConnectCamera()`, etc.
In my main code I use an object `MasterCamera mCamera = CameraSelector.GetCamera();`
with `CameraSelector` checking whether a camera from A, B or C is connected, and returns that object (e.g. `CameraFromManufacturerA`)

This works perfectly fine in theory, but one of these camera's API needs to use the WindowsMessageCallback (`WndProc`), thus I need to include for that camera only `Windows.System.Forms.Form`

Since C# does not allow multiple inheritance, and afaik Form has no interface class, I have to make `MasterCamera` inherit from `Windows.System.Forms.Form`

I do not want that, so how can I go around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use  MasterCamera { ... } as a Class but use it as Interface
like:

public interface MasterCamera { ... }

and it must work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Didn't know you can use an interface as an object to call functions from.

Comment: This provides no means for implementing the common functionality.

Comment: That is true, but since every camera's manufacturers API is completely different, there is close to no common code at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem with inheritance, which is why the GoF state "Favour composition over inheritance"

You could use the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. Instead of deriving different types of `MasterCamera`, instead derive different types of `ICameraFunctionality`, and store an object of that instance in your `MasterCamera` (or rather just `Camera`) class.

That way MasterCamera just does the common work, but calls its `ICameraFunctionality` instance to perform specific work.

Answer (score 1):

What if you simply *invert* dependency in your code. 
Create a `Form` class that overrides `WindowsMessageCallback` and is able to host `MasterCamera` object, which would be that child `Camera` class that you need.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying `Inheritance`. Give a try to `Composition` also.

Can't `Camera` be contained in a `Form`?